# Get integer value from the string Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, int

I want to take the integer value from the string address. for example

http://www.testtest.com/?page=12

here, i want to take "12" in this address.

How can i do this in asp.net mvc ?

Answer (score 3):

In your controller, create a method with `int` as a parameter

```
public ActionResult Index(int page)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

@Ardman is correct, MVC will translate the value in the query string and convert it to a variable in the ActionResult Function.

Be aware though, the example provided **requires** an int called page to be passed so you can do the following to overcome this.

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
    if(page.HasValue())
    {
        // Do somthing with the var
    }
    // Do something
}
```

You can also use the old method,

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var Page Request.QueryString["page"]; //return page query string param as a string
}
```

Hope that provides a little more info.